# WPF foreground inheritance

Tags: wpf, inheritance, styles, controls, themes

I created a simple style in WPF and I cannot figure out what case A works, but not case B.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        TextBlock.Foreground="Red"
                        TextElement.Foreground="Yellow"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

Case A:
<Button Content="Test A"/> // background is Yellow

Case B:
<Button>
<TextBlock Text="Test B"/> // background is black
</Button>
```

I would like to create a style for a button that change text color of its content via the ContentPresenter.

Could someone explains what is missing to make case B to work?
(Ideally it should work with any content that have a Foreground property, not only TextBlocks).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In style you mentioned TargetType="Button" so its only affected to button not TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Button's Foreground property via another Setter:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

Alternatively, add a TextBlock Style to the ControlTemplate's Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I was looking for something more generic, and for the reason why case B don't work. In both cases, its a TextBlock inside a ContentPresenter. Moreover, the same code works perfectly if I use UWP instead of WPF.

In fact I was trying to replicate the same behavior than UWP. Being able to use a button style that change foreground color (ex: TextBlockButtonStyle), but with a content such as a StackPanel that contains an Icon and a TextBlock. Don't know why it works in UWP but not in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Clemens, but in fact I would like to change foreground of one part of the template only, not the foreground of the control itself. Button is just a simple example here.

I am using the ContentPresenter in triggers too:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#66FFFFFF"/>
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```